# Publishing Android Library from JCenter to Maven Central

Tags: java, android, bintray, jcenter, maven-central

I was following [these](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) steps
to submitted a [File Picker](https://bintray.com/angads25/maven/filepicker) Android Library on JCenter through Bintray and Android Studio. The library has been linked to JCenter. I have provided with all details like Sonatype account details and GPG keys, Also have created an Issue in Sonatype as a new Project. However, when I try to sync library to maven central, I am getting following error:

```
Last Synced: Never
Last Sync Status: Sync Failed
Last Sync Errors: Failed to promote repository: central_bundles-7671. Server response: <nexus-error> <errors> <error> <id>*</id> <msg>User 'angads25' missing 'promote' permission for staging profile: 7edbe315063867</msg> </error> </errors> </nexus-error> Dropping existing partial staging repository.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is right there, in the error message.

It looks like you don't have the permissions to publish to Maven Central under the path you are trying to publish. Please check that the group ID of your project matches the group ID you requested the ownership for in Sonatype JIRA.

Comment: How long will it take to show the library in maven central search result?

Comment: It's Sonatype, so it depends. They promise up to four hours.